Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D:\Reactnative\myapp> npm run android

myapp@0.0.1 android
react-native run-android

info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
13 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 10 up-to-date
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.


[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 18s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1m 18s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS D:\Reactnative\myapp> gradle --stop
gradle : The term 'gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

gradle --stop

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gradle:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




PS D:\Reactnative\myapp>
